# x86/x64 Add Displacement addressing

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit

I'm writing a compiler for x86/x64 CPU instructions and I can't seem to figure out what people mean by 'displacement' address.  For example the Add instruction is detailed here:
http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/X77_0150_encoding_add_edx_displacement.htm

I'm just trying to implement the add instruction where a register is added to a normal memory address.  The problem is, the address is a 'displacement address'.  Does that mean the address is a signed value that's the offset from the instruction location?

Comment: Are you generating assembly code? Can't you generate C code, or use LLVM? Or emit machine code with http://code.google.com/p/asmjit/ or other libraries? Do you understand well the x86/64 instruction set? Did you study http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a few different forms of indirect operands in x86:

1. [reg]
2. [reg + displacement]
3. [displacement]
4. [reg * constant + reg]
5. [reg * constant + reg + displacement]

The "displacement" is just a constant that gets added to the rest of the address. In cases where there is no component of the address other than the constant, it is still called a "displacement". This is mainly for consistency with the other addressing forms.

Another way to look at it is that all addresses are of the form

[reg * constant + reg + displacement]

With each of the components allowing a value of 0.

The [displacement] form is just the encoding where all components other than the displacement are zero.

As a compiler writer the last 2 forms are particularly interesting. They make it easy to encode things like `pArray[index]->field + 1`in a single instruction.

Comment: Ok so how does [reg * constant + reg + displacement] get encoded into a machine instruction?  Say I have an array at memory location 0x00000001 and I want to access the index of it which is AL.  I guess I want to use the move instruction and do MOV AH 0x00000001[AL].  I think that's just [reg+displacement].  Section 6 of this page shows encoding the R/M byte but it's really confusing: http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/lecture.html

Comment: Take a look at volume 2 of the intel manual. Each instruction specifies its encoding forms. Encoding forms that list r/m operands accept register or memory operands in the mod/rm byte.

Comment: Take a look at volume 2 of the intel manual. Each instruction specifies its encoding forms. Encoding forms that list r/m operands accept register or memory operands in the mod/rm byte. In chapter 2 of volume 2, section 2.1 there is a table that shows the meaning of the mod r/m byte. The forms that have [--][--] listed denote an encoding that uses the SIB byte. SIB addressing is of the form reg*constant + reg. Some forms of the mod/rm byte indicate that the SIB byte is followed by a displacement. Those gives the reg*constant + reg + constant forms. There is a table explaining SIB as well.

Comment: Oh ok thanks!  I'm also reading that on 64-bit processors the displacement address is still 32 bits??  So on anything larger you have to load it into a register to read it?

Comment: @Scott, Could one use register as a displacement?
While assembling `lea %rax(%r12), %r14` gcc spits `Error: junk (%r12) after register`.

Comment: No. It wouldn't be a "displacement" if it was a register. The displacement is a constant that follows the modrm byte. You can use the sum of 2 registers though.  Take a look at the intel manual.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "special add that takes a displacement", that page is being unnecessarily confusing - this is just part of the normal memory operand encoding.

`add` is a fairly standard instruction that is encoded the same way as all the alu-ops are: there is a special case for using `al` as destination and an immediate as the source (`04 ib`), using `ax/eax/rax` as the destination and an immediate as the source (`+ 05 imm`), three versions of `add r/m, imm` (one for 8bit destinations, one for wider destinations and a sign-extended 8bit source, one for wider destinations and a wide source), and of course an `add r, r/m` and `add r/m, r`.

This is just a special case of `add r, r/m`, where the `r/m` takes the form of a displacement: see note #1 of [ModRM encoding](http://www.sandpile.org/x86/opc_rm.htm).

So they just mean `add edx, [sdword]`. (but they misencoded the reg field, `edx` corresponds to `010`, not `011`)

Comment: So to add say AL (8 bit register 0) to the memory location 0x00000000, the CPU would accept (in hex) 00 05 00000000?

Answer (score 4):

That page is not accurate. The "add that takes a displacement" which it's talking about refers to the form `add r[16|32], r/m[16|32]` or `add edx, [0xdisp]` as you might see it in a disassembler's output. Assuming it's talking about the ADD instruction with opcode `0x03`,

- Encoding the `edx` register destination and specifying a 32-bit displacement as effective address in the ModR/M byte would give it the value of 0x15 (refer to the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Vol. 2, page 41, table 2-2).
- The effect of this instruction is to add the dword at the memory address `disp` to the contents of `edx`.
- The actual encoding of the instruction would thus be: `\x03\x15\x00\x00\x00\x01`, for a displacement of 1 byte.