# Traversing a 2-d array

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86

I'm having trouble understanding how to traverse a 2-d array in x86 assembly language. I am missing a bit of understanding. This is what I have so far.

The issue is the lines with `//offset` and `//moving through array`
For the `//offset` line the error I am getting is "non constant expression in second operand" 
and also
"ebx: illegal register in second operand"

For the next line I get the error
"edx: illegal register in second operand"

```
    mov esi, dim
    mul esi
    mov eax, 0 // row index
    mov ebx, 0 // column index
    mov ecx, dim
StartFor:
    cmp ecx, esi
    jge EndFor
    lea edi, image;
    mov edx, [eax *dim + ebx] // offset
    mov dl, byte ptr [edi + esi*edx] // moving through array
    mov edx, edi
    and edx, 0x80
    cmp edx, 0x00
    jne OverThreshold
    mov edx, 0xFF


OverThreshold:
    mov edx, 0x0
```

Comment: What does `need to fix this` mean? Can you explain what the actual problem is?

Comment: That was just something unrelated. I edited my post to better explain my issue. Sorry, new poster

Comment: OK. I don't think you can do that much math in an offset. IIRC, you're limited to [REGISTER + CONSTANT_OFFSET]. You may have to calculate the offset manually (ADD and MUL), or just keep track of it as you go.

Comment: Ah, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329611/x86-x64-add-displacement-addressing) we go - you can multiply by a constant, but you can't multiply two registers.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Okay I changed it mov edx, eax*dim(number of row/cols as parameter) + ebx. Still getting the same errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki, including the [list of addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058400/224132).

You can scale an index register by a constant, but you can't multiply two registers in an addressing mode.  You'll have to do that yourself (e.g. with `imul edx, esi`, if the number of columns isn't a compile time constant.  If it's a power-of-2 constant, you can shift, or even use a scaled addressing mode like `[reg + reg*8]`).

---

re: edit:  `*dim` should work if `dim` is defined with something like `dim equ 8`.  If it's a memory location holding a value, then of course it's not going to work.  The scale factor can be 1, 2, 4, or 8.  (The machine code format has room for a 2-bit shift count, which is why the options are limited.)

---

I'd also recommend loading with `movzx` to zero-extend a byte into `edx`, instead of only writing `dl` (the low byte).  Actually nvm, your code doesn't need that.  In fact, you overwrite the value you loaded with `edi`.  I assume that's a bug.

---

You can replace

```
imul  edx, esi
mov dl, byte ptr [edi + edx]   ; note the different addressing mode
mov edx, edi                   ; bug?  throw away the value you just loaded
and edx, 0x80                  ; AND already sets flags according to the result
cmp edx, 0x00                  ; so this is redundant
jne OverThreshold
```

with

```
imul   edx, esi
test   0x80, byte ptr [edi + edx]   ; AND, discard the result and set flags.
jnz
```

---

Of course, instead of multiplying inside the inner loop, you can just add the `columns` in the outer loop.  This is called [Strength Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction).  So you do `p+=1` along each row, and `p+=cols` to go from row to row.  Or if you don't need to care about rows and columns, you can just iterate over the flat memory of the 2D array.

Answer (score 1):

A 2-dimensional array is just an interpretation of a sequence of bytes. You'll have to choose in which order to store the items. For example, you might choose ["row-major order"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order).

I've written a demo where a buffer is filled with a sequence of numbers. Then the sequence is interpreted as single- and two-dimensional array.

**tx86.s**

```
%define ITEM_SIZE 4

    extern printf

    section .bss

cols:   equ     3
rows:   equ     4
buf:    resd    cols * rows
c:      resd    1
r:      resd    1

    section .data

fmt:        db "%-4d", 0          ; fmt string, '0'
fmt_nl:     db 10, 0              ; "\n", '0'

    section .text           ; Code section.

    global main

main:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

    ; fill buf
    mov     ecx, cols * rows - 1
    mov     [buf + ITEM_SIZE], ecx
.fill_buf:
    mov     [buf + ecx * ITEM_SIZE], ecx
    dec     ecx
    jnz     .fill_buf

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; buf as 1-dimensional array
; buf[c] = [buf + c * ITEM_SIZE]
    xor     ecx, ecx
    mov     [c], ecx
.lp1d:
    mov     ecx, [c]

    push    dword [buf + ecx * ITEM_SIZE]
    push    dword fmt
    call    printf

    mov     ecx, [c]
    inc     ecx
    mov     [c], ecx
    cmp     ecx, cols * rows
    jl      .lp1d

    ; print new line
    push    dword fmt_nl
    call    printf

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; buf as 2-dimensional array
; buf[r][c] = [buf + (r * cols + c) * ITEM_SIZE]
    xor     ecx, ecx
    mov     [r], ecx
.lp1:
    xor     ecx, ecx
    mov     [c], ecx
.lp2:
    ; calculate address
    mov     eax, [r]
    mov     edx, cols
    mul     edx         ; eax = r * cols
    add     eax, [c]    ; eax = r * cols + c

    ; print buf[r][c]
    push    dword [buf + eax * ITEM_SIZE]
    push    dword fmt
    call    printf

    ; next column
    mov     ecx, [c]
    inc     ecx
    mov     [c], ecx
    cmp     ecx, cols
    jl      .lp2

    ; print new line
    push    dword fmt_nl
    call    printf

    ; next row
    mov     ecx, [r]
    inc     ecx
    mov     [r], ecx
    cmp     ecx, rows
    jl      .lp1


    mov     esp, ebp
    pop     ebp         ; restore stack

    xor     eax, eax    ; normal exit code
    ret
```

**Buidling(on Linux)**

```
nasm -f elf32 -l tx86.lst tx86.s
gcc -Wall -g -O0 -m32 -o tx86 tx86.o
```

**Running**

```
./tx86
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  
0   1   2   
3   4   5   
6   7   8   
9   10  11
```